# How to draw a 2D bounding box of a 3D object

Tags: python, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

I'd like to visualize a bounding box of a 3D object in the 2D rendered image like in the example image below.

[image: Bounding box example]

My idea is to use the line draw function presented [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9324/straight-lines-with-no-face-freestyle) but I don't know how to transform the 3D bounding box coordinates in the object into 2D coordinates for the line drawing.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7198/save-the-2d-bounding-box-of-an-object-in-rendered-image-to-a-text-file